# Firebase storage fails to download file for Android OS 16

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've an Android app which downloads file from Firebase Storage, It is working fine with Android API level 23 and above. However, For version like Android API level 16 it fails with following exception:

```
05-15 16:42:32.921 3909-3952/com.X.Y E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
    Unable to open stream
    java.io.IOException: Unable to open stream
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.zzp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzq.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzp.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzp.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zzn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzw.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.zzp(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.zza(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzq.run(Unknown Source) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Code to download:**

```
final StorageReference pathReference = mStoragePath.getReference().child(mRootPath + inPath);

final StreamDownloadTask downloadTask = pathReference.getStream();
```

**Dependencies:**

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2
```

Comment: firebase dependency version?

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2 and com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2

Answer (score -1):

This can maybe happen if google play services isn't updated on your phone. Make sure that you have the latest version.

If your version is up to date check in setContentLanguage you should use only 2 letters (E.g. "en"). Also you should check this [answer](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/116) in github which depend in your problem

Comment: @Sameer Thigale this answer help you?